# Enzyme: How to test props change of a container component?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs, enzyme

To render the container component connected to redux store, I'm using this function to render the component

```
function render(Component, props, storeData) {
  const mockStore = configureStore([thunkMiddleware]);
  const store = mockStore(storeData);

  return mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Component {...props} />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Now, I need to test the props change of the Component rendered but it looks like `ReactWrapper.setProps` only works for the Root component.
`MyComponent` is a container component that is connected to store using `connect`.

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('should work at props change', () => {
    const wrapper = render(MyComponent, { value: 1 }, initialStoreValue);

    wrapper.find(MyComponent).setProps({ value: 2});
    
    // then expect something.
  });
});
```

Comment: A similar issue happens when I use a component using Radium.
I had to wrap the component with `<StyleRoot>` to mount that component and because of that, I was not able to update the props.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to consider:

1. `redux-mock-store` allows to pass a function as state source - `redux-mock-store` will call that function every time
2. to trigger re-rendering component with `useSelector` or `connect()` we can just `dispatch()` with any action type. Literally any.
3. We need to wrap updating store into `act()` or otherwise it might not work and definitely will complain with `console.error`.

So keeping that in mind we can enhance `render`:

```
function render(Component, props, initialStoreData) {
  let currentStoreData = initialStoreData;
  const mockStore = configureStore([thunkMiddleware]);
  const store = mockStore(() => currentStoreData);

  const wrapper = mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Component {...props} />
    </Provider>
  );
  const updateStore = (newStoreData) => {
    currentStoreData = newStoreData;
    act(() => {
      store.dispatch({ type: '' }); // just to trigger re-rendering components
    });
  }
  return { wrapper, updateStore };
}
```

And then in test:

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('does something when store changes somehow', () => {
    const { wrapper, updateStore } = render(MyComponent, { value: 1 }, initialStoreValue);
    
    updateStore({ someReduxValue: 2});

    // then expect something.
  });
});
```

Comment: But this doesn't update the props given to the component, does it?

Comment: I don't understand question. If component under the test is actually `connect()` + underlying component, then underlying component will get new props after store is updated. And everything inside that consumes props will be different(that you actually better to check instead of prop change detection - whether button hides, text label changes etc)

Comment: or do you mean that with this approach real reducers does not jump in and triggering an action does not update store accordingly? but that's the point: you just mock store data instead of mocking every single `fetch` or other 3rd party API calls.